# Convert Expected values of low frequency data to high frequency.

Tags: probability-distributions, machine-learning, expected-value

I have a frequency data (observations separated by 1hours) for daily sales of Product ‘A’ and Product ‘B’.  30,000 days of observations are recorded.

In the data, the expected sales(Exp_A, Exp_B) values of each productare given per day. Everything else is observed per hours (there are about 15 more variables). I want to break it down to hourly so I can train the data and implement a predictive model.

The data has two columns labeled with the number of sales per hour for each product.

I thought about first to obtain mean of sales for each hour. 
What would I do with it?

I would be grateful for any suggestions or provide a link to a publication or a topic I should look in to...